# Bouncing Ball animation

Tags: java

I was trying to add some things to the **bouncing ball** code but **during animation mode the screen hangs** after some intervals(takes break) and recontinues again.I am not able to judge why this is going on?

Here is the code:

```
public class Programme {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 5;
        double[] rx = new double[10];
        double[] ry = new double[10];
        double[] vx = new double[10];
        double[] vy = new double[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            rx[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            ry[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            vx[i] = 0.02;
            vy[i] = 0.03;
        }
        double radius = .06;
        StdDraw.setXscale(-1.0, +1.0);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-1.0, +1.0);
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                if (Math.abs(rx[i] + vx[i]) + radius > 1.0) {
                    vx[i] = -vx[i];
                    StdAudio.play("music.wav");
                }
                if (Math.abs(ry[i] + vy[i]) + radius > 1.0) {
                    vy[i] = -vy[i];
                    StdAudio.play("music.wav");
                }
                rx[i] = rx[i] + vx[i];
                ry[i] = ry[i] + vy[i];

                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GREEN);
                StdDraw.filledSquare(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    StdDraw.picture(rx[j], ry[j], "game.gif");
                }
                StdDraw.show(10);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You could at least format your code properly

Comment: Please consider code cleanup before you post here

Comment: game.gif is an image and music.wav is the sound which comes when the image comes in contact with the boundary.

Comment: hmmm my friend faced this issue when cooperating sound with animation, try to run the application without sound(comment the lines `StdAudio.play("music.wav")`) , post the result of the experiment here

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.It helped.But can u tell what can I do to accomodate the music with it also?@niceman

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes basically from the fact that you're playing sound and doing animation in the same thread, you have to make your application multithreaded with one thread for playing sound and the other showing animation.

One note to say is that StdDraw.picture may need to read from the file game.gif to draw the image, I don't have experience with StdDraw but reading the file on every iteration will slow down the application , I think it would be faster(but more RAM consuming) to read the file outside the while loop into a two-dimensional array and use the array inside the loop to draw instead.

Comment: @Ranger sorry my friend but that is a broad subject, if you're asking about references then java certification book was good for me